# Can android connect to an existing database?

Tags: android

Im currently creating a salon booking application for a school project and platform has helped me achieve alot so far. But my current problem is that i want to connect to an existing mysql database. Could anyone please help and show me how im new to android. 
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Sure you can. Create an API to interact with your MySQL database.

Comment: please read through this http://www.trustingeeks.com/connect-android-app-to-mysql-database/

Answer (score 2):

The best implementation for this action is to set the android device to send a Post/Get to a server PHP/ASP/JSP etc.. let the server to make all the procedures like find what information the device wanted and return it into json encoding
for example the post request include the ID of a student when the post arrives to the server ,the server will find all the information from that specific ID and will return all the information about him into Json ,when the data received to the device ,you can store the data into the local database(Mysqlite)  if you want.

Android Post and waiting for the data by the server

```
    class JSONAsyncTaskTeiEg extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {


    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialogOff.setMessage("Loading Data_TeiEG...");

    }
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {


        int tei_id;
        int branch_id;
        String city;
        String region;
        String nameTEI;
        String nameBRANCH;
        double longitude;
        double latitude;

        DBAdapterTeiEgTable adapter = new DBAdapterTeiEgTable(MainMenu.this);
        adapter.open();

        try {

            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                data=new String(data.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");

                JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(data);
                LatLng point;

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);


                    tei_id=object.getInt(DBAdapterTeiTable.KEY_ID);
                    branch_id=object.getInt(DBAdapterTeiTable.KEY_BRANCHID);
                    city=object.getString(DBAdapterTeiTable.KEY_CITY);
                    region=object.getString(DBAdapterTeiTable.KEY_REGION);
                    nameTEI=object.getString(DBAdapterTeiTable.KEY_NAMETEI);
                    nameBRANCH=object.getString(DBAdapterTeiTable.KEY_NAMEBRANCH);
                    longitude=object.getDouble(DBAdapterTeiTable.KEY_LONGITUDE);
                    latitude=object.getDouble(DBAdapterTeiTable.KEY_LATITUDE);





                    adapter.updateRecord( tei_id, branch_id, nameTEI, nameBRANCH , region,  city, longitude, latitude );
                    point=null;
                }

                adapter.close();
                return true;
            }



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        adapter.close();

        return false;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {


        if(result)
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data transfered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch Data_TeiEG from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dialogOff.cancel();
        }



    }
}
```

Server listen the post request and return the data

```
foreach ($hugeArray as $key => $value) 
    if($value['job_data_id']==$dep_data){

        $job_full_driver = $value['job_full_driver'];
        $job_half_driver = $value['job_half_driver'];
        $combination =$value['isCombination'];

        if($combination==='False')
            foreach ($hugeArray2 as $key => $value2) 
                if($value2['job_half_driver']===$job_half_driver)
                {

                         $job_data_id =$value2['job_data_id'];
                         $job_name= $value2['job_name'];
                         $job_id= $value2['job_id'];

                         $job_half_driver = $value2['job_half_driver'];

                         $dep_job_name= $value2['dep_job_name'];
                         $dep_website= $value2['dep_website'];
                         $dep_job_drive= $value2['dep_job_drive'];
                         $description= $value2['description'];


                        $description=$value2['description'];
                        $inf_employment_public_sector=$value2['inf_employment_public_sector'];
                        $inf_employment_private_sector=$value2['inf_employment_private_sector'];
                        $inf_self_employment=$value2['inf_self_employment'];
                        $graduate_studies_greece=$value2['graduate_studies_greece'];
                        $graduate_studies_abroad=$value2['graduate_studies_abroad'];
                        $inf_for_the_proffesional_rights=$value2['inf_for_the_proffesional_rights'];
                        $profesional_and_scientific_bodies=$value2['profesional_and_scientific_bodies'];


                        $data = array(

                        'job_data_id' => $job_data_id,
                        'job_name' => $job_name,
                        'job_id' => $job_id,
                        'job_half_driver' => $job_half_driver,
                        'job_full_driver' => $job_full_driver,
                        'description' => $description,
                        'inf_employment_public_sector' => $inf_employment_public_sector,
                        'inf_employment_private_sector' => $inf_employment_private_sector,
                        'inf_self_employment' => $inf_self_employment,
                        'graduate_studies_greece' => $graduate_studies_greece,
                        'graduate_studies_abroad' => $graduate_studies_abroad,
                        'inf_for_the_proffesional_rights' => $inf_for_the_proffesional_rights,
                        'profesional_and_scientific_bodies' => $profesional_and_scientific_bodies


                        );



                        $json = json_encode ($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

                        echo $json;

                        break;




                }











    }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. I dnt want to use the local mysqllite database because i have to take into consideration that the application is going to be used by real ppl who go to a real salon therfore the database would then reside in a cloud where real clients information of the salon will b stored